# Keeping selected section / row after UiTableView reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I've got a `UITableView` that when selecting a `UITableViewCell` I call a web service to fetch new data and then reload the `UITableView` with the new data.

Now, the selected row will always be part of the new data that comes back. However the number of rows in a section won't be constant.

I am trying to keep selection on the row that was selected after I reload the table view. I saved the indexPath from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. However when I call:

```
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath 
                                animated:NO 
                          scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Nothing happens and my row I selected is no longer selected after the reload. Is there anyway to keep selection after a reload of `UITableView`?

Comment: Can you add some kind of selection flag to the data?

Comment: The data is in an array - I get a new copy of the data each time selection happens as the data changes. What is constant and always guaranteed is getting back the selected item from the new data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827176/save-selected-row-in-uitableview-after-reloaddata

Comment: Put the selected item in a local iVar, put an equality check in the cellforrowatindex path, so when its reloading the cells, it will compare in incoming data with you saved iVar. If its a match the you call the selecteRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
      [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath 
                                  animated:NO 
                            scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
});
```

Also, make sure, that your `self.indexPath` property will represent the same cell after reloading the `UITableView`.

Comment: This didn't help. I think maybe the problem is that the cell moves to a different row. Its still in the same section but moves from row 4 (for example) to row 1 as its the only item left in that section?

Comment: So you shouldn't rely to indexPath. You need to save selected element of your data and find it index in new data after reload. With this index you will be able to create NSIndexPath object and select valid cell

Comment: How would I save the selected element? The data model gets refreshed when I reload the tableview. I don't store the data it gets free'd from memory when I no longer need it. I can get selection working if I save the index path as 0. But as you pointed out, this may lead to issues if there is more than one row..

Comment: Then I believe you have two options. Store your data and selected element during all table view life cycle, or keep info about selected element  directly in data

Comment: Save by indexPath, i think it can not work because data you get from server is always changes. When you click a row, you save key-id (i means key that you can distinguish between cells). After that for-loop to find that key, at that time, you will get actual indexPath.

Answer (score 1):

Before `reloadData`, preserve the selected index path(s). After reload, use `selectRowAtIndexPath:`, to set selected rows back again e.g.

```
NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *indexPathsForSelectedRows = self.itemsTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows; // multiple selection

NSIndexPath *indexPathForSelectedRow = self.itemsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;   // single selection

[self.tableView reloadData];

[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPathForSelectedRow animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone]; // single selection

for (int i = 0; i < indexPathsForSelectedRows.count; i++) {
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPathsForSelectedRows[i] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone]; // multiple selection
}
```